# How can I update to Amazon Linux 2 ECS optimized container instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

Since I started using AWS ECS I have followed the [AWS ECS reference architecture](https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation). This reference architecture uses Amazon Linux, and I would like to update to Amazon Linux 2, but I'm not sure what I'm required to do in order to make this transition successfully.

There is an [issue on the GitHub repo for this reference architecture](https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation/issues/97) but it has not received any attention in months despite several people asking for help. From what I understand, here are some issues that need to be addressed when using the Amazon Linux 2 ECS optimized AMI:

- `sysvinit` is no longer supported on Amazon Linux 2; `systemd` should be used instead.
- Amazon Linux 2 stores docker logs in `journald` which is not currently supported by Cloud ([described here](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-ecs-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/using_cloudwatch_logs.md#configuring-and-starting-the-cloudwatch-logs-agent))

I have an open source project that I am using to learn CloudFormation and AWS; [here's a link to the `ecs-cluster.yaml` file](https://gitlab.com/verbose-equals-true/django-postgres-vue-gitlab-ecs/blob/develop/cloudformation/infrastructure/ecs-cluster.yaml#L104) that describes the ECS cluster and container instance that I am trying to update.

I have heard that some people are using Amazon Linux 2 with ECS and I would like to update as well since support for Amazon Linux (1) ends in about 6 months. Does anyone know what other considerations I would need to make in order to use Amazon Linux 2 with ECS? Debugging this issue is time consuming and I'm not sure what options and configurations I should be trying.

Comment: Should be pretty simple changes. Here is a reference template using Linux2 AMI -- https://github.com/widdix/aws-cf-templates/blob/master/ecs/cluster.yaml

Comment: Thank you for the resource @spinkus. I noticed that this template uses `sysvinit`, but I thought that wasn't compatible with Amazon Linux 2 AMIs [https://cloudonaut.io/migrating-to-amazon-linux-2/](https://cloudonaut.io/migrating-to-amazon-linux-2/). I can still give this a try, however.

Comment: There is a compatability layer on most distros including AWS Linux 2 for sysv init scripts.

Comment: @briancaffey have you tried using [commands](https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-advanced-cloudformation/discussion/-Kpm2dXiivAKYnqWDGwQ/Cfn%20Init%20and%20linux%20systemd%3F) section for resolving `systemd` ?.

Comment: Hi @Imran, I haven't tried this but I imagine that it is something that I would need to do.

Comment: You can use something like https://advantageous.github.io/systemd-cloud-watch/ to send journald logs to CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: I wonder if there is a solution for this yet.  I'm still stuck with amazon linux 1.  When I upgrade to the AMI for amazon linux 2, I get a Cloudformation update error, and rolls back.